# Image size in single category post being overriden

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this in a single post category template:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
          the_post_thumbnail(array( 200, 200 ));
      }
?>
```

This is working except for the fact that the thumbnail, no matter what I put in the paramater, is showing at full size so it's huge on the page. When I inspect it, the 200x200 is marked out and it's using  `width:100%` and `height:auto`. Obviously there's a global setting for single thumbnails somewhere, which is fine, but I need to control the images specifically for this category page to be 200x200.

Is there a better solution to force the thumbnail size here?

Comment: can you possibly share the page where you are seeing this image? or at least an image of the `img` tag. I think custom image sizes aren't actually generated in WP but only added as classes that the user needs to then handle. You might be better of creating a [custom size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/#comment-311) and find a plugin to regenerate your image sizes

Comment: Thank you, I had already started looking at custom sizes and regenerating a few minutes ago and I'm thinking of going that route

Comment: That is great! It should surely solve you problem